# Is the algorithm of processing raw data from PiCamera to get the JPEG that raspistill obtains opensource?

Tags: raspicam

I'd like to learn how exactly the raw data from PiCamera are processed by the system to yield the final JPEG that `raspistill` saves. Is this algorithm available as opensource code? Or is it hidden in a binary firmware blob?

Note: I know that I can convert the raw data to DNG format and use software like RawTherapee etc., but this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for what *is actually done* by the system, not what I can use to try to emulate this.

Comment: You can check the source for yourself at https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/tree/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam

Comment: @Dirk I have seen the source for RaspiStill. It simply uses the MMAL, which doesn't answer my question in any way.

Comment: Would have been helpful if you had added that info to your question...goodbye

Comment: Have you looked at the [MMAL header file?](https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/blob/master/interface/mmal/mmal.h)

Comment: @Seamus it doesn't seem to have any pointers to the code doing the demosaicing, black level subtraction, denoising, color balancing etc....

Comment: @Ruslan: It would seem to me that ***if*** those functions are implemented, there would have to be a link to the code that executes it. Perhaps in another header file, perhaps in a library called at runtime. I don't know the answer to your question; I offered the comment in case you'd overlooked the header file.